# How to insert a primary key record with multiple foreign key records based on a stored procedure called with ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I am building a content / knowledge base system based on ASP.NET Core. A page will show a rich text editor with multiple dropdowns (the number of dropdowns is not limited but most likely not more than 10).

For example, the content in the rich text editor is about growing organic coffee in a tropical environment in silt soil. In this example, there will be 3 dropdown boxes:

1. crop is coffee
2. Climate is tropical
3. Soil type is silt

When clicking submit the page will store the content in the content table and add three records in the classification-content table which is a table for n-m relation between the classification values and the content.

In SQL I would like to do this with a single transaction in order to guarantee that all is inserted or none.

I was thinking of creating a temp table and first insert the 3 values in there. Then call with a stored procedure to add the content and copy the records in the temp table to the classification-content table as a single transaction.

This, as I don't see an option to put an array of values that I have in C# into a stored procedure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Hi Dale, just checked a little. Looks promising. Will check more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table Value Parameter but also use Begin, Commit & RollBack Transaction.You can do something like below

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Content] AS TABLE
(
    [Column1]                 VARCHAR (1)   NOT NULL,
    [Column2]                 VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    [ColumnN]                  VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ContentClassification] AS TABLE
(
    [Column1]                 VARCHAR (1)   NOT NULL,
    [Column2]                 VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    [ColumnN]                  VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_CONTENT_INSERT]
    @Content as [Content] READONLY,
    @ContentClassification as [ContentClassification] READONLY,
    @ErrorStatus int Out

AS

BEGIN TRY

     BEGIN TRANSACTION

     -- Insert in to Content
      INSERT INTO [tbl_ContentTable]
      (     [Column1], [Column2],... [ColumnN] )
      SELECT  [Column1], [Column2],..[ColumnN] FROM @Content

      -- Insert in to ContentClassification
      INSERT INTO [tbl_ContentClassification]
      (     [Column1], [Column2],... [ColumnN] )
      SELECT  [Column1], [Column2],...[ColumnN] FROM @ContentClassification

     set  @OutStatus = 1;

     COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
     set  @OutStatus = -1;
END CATCH
```

The above will ensure for a given parent all dependents are inserted. In case of error it would be a rollback.

Alternatively, you can also do the same in C# Code using BeginTransaction Object of a connection Object. The below is the code snippet from MSDN
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=netframework-4.8

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                SqlTransaction transaction;

                // Start a local transaction.
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {
                    command.CommandText =
                        "Insert into tbl_ContentTable (Column1, Column2, ... ColumnN) VALUES (V1, V2,...VN)";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.CommandText =
                         "Insert into tbl_ContentTable (Column1, Column2, ... ColumnN) VALUES (V1, V2,...VN)";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                    Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

                    // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                        // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                        // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                        // a closed connection.
                        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this Helps!